# How to extract value of CPU idle from sar command using AWK

Tags: unix, awk, cpu

From the outut of a `sar` command, I want to extract only the lines in which the `%iowait` value is higher than a set threshold.
I tried using AWK but somehow I'm not able to perform the action.

```
sar -u -f sa12 | sed 's/\./,/g' | awk -f" " '{ if ( $7 -gt 0 ) print $0 }'
```

I tried to substitute the `.` with `,` and using `-gt` but still no joy.
Can someone suggest a solution?

Comment: `.`(dot) is a special character, it means every character. first escape the dot with `\.`(backslash)

Comment: Please show the result of the `sar -r fa12` command.

Comment: `sar -u -f sa12 | awk '$7'` should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need entire line output of `sar -u` with `iowait > 0.01` then, we can use this ,

**Command**

```
sar -u | grep -v "CPU" | awk '$7 > 0.01'
```

**Output will be similar to**

```
03:40:01 AM     all      3.16      0.00      0.05      0.11      0.00     96.68
04:40:01 PM     all      0.19      0.00      0.05      0.02      0.00     99.74
```

if wish to out specific fields, say only `iowait`, we can use as given below,

**Command to out specific field(s),**

```
sar -u | grep -v "CPU" | awk '{if($7 > 0.01 ) print $7}'
```

**Output will be**

```
0.11
0.02
```

*Note* : `grep -v` is used just to remove the headings in the output

Hope this helps,

Comment: `{if($7 > 0.01 ) print $0}` idiomatically written as `$7>0.01`

Comment: @karakfa , Yes it is .. was given an answer where we can simply change the filed number to get the output required .. edited to add mentioned way too.. Thanks

Comment: you can eliminate `grep` as well.  `awk '!/CPU/ && $7>0.01'`

Answer (score 0):

My `sar -u` gives several lines similar to the following:

```
Linux 4.4.0-127-generic (v1)    06/12/2018      _x86_64_        (1 CPU)

12:00:01 AM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
12:05:01 AM     all      0.29      0.00      0.30      0.01      0.00     99.40
12:15:01 AM     all      0.33      0.00      0.34      0.00      0.00     99.32
12:25:01 AM     all      0.33      0.00      0.30      0.01      0.00     99.36
12:35:01 AM     all      0.31      0.00      0.29      0.01      0.00     99.39
12:45:01 AM     all      0.33      0.00      0.32      0.01      0.00     99.35
12:55:01 AM     all      0.32      0.00      0.30      0.00      0.00     99.38
01:05:01 AM     all      0.32      0.00      0.28      0.00      0.00     99.39
01:15:01 AM     all      0.33      0.00      0.30      0.01      0.00     99.37
01:25:01 AM     all      0.31      0.00      0.30      0.01      0.00     99.39
01:35:01 AM     all      0.31      0.00      0.33      0.00      0.00     99.36
01:45:01 AM     all      0.31      0.00      0.28      0.01      0.00     99.40
01:55:01 AM     all      0.31      0.00      0.30      0.00      0.00     99.38
02:05:01 AM     all      0.31      0.00      0.28      0.01      0.00     99.40
02:15:01 AM     all      0.32      0.00      0.30      0.01      0.00     99.38
02:25:01 AM     all      0.31      0.00      0.30      0.01      0.00     99.38
02:35:01 AM     all      0.33      0.00      0.33      0.00      0.00     99.33
02:45:01 AM     all      0.35      0.00      0.32      0.01      0.00     99.32
02:55:01 AM     all      0.28      0.00      0.30      0.00      0.00     99.42
03:05:01 AM     all      0.32      0.00      0.31      0.00      0.00     99.37
03:15:01 AM     all      0.34      0.00      0.30      0.01      0.00     99.36
03:25:01 AM     all      0.32      0.00      0.29      0.01      0.00     99.38
03:35:01 AM     all      0.33      0.00      0.26      0.00      0.00     99.40
03:45:01 AM     all      0.34      0.00      0.29      0.00      0.00     99.36
03:55:01 AM     all      0.30      0.00      0.28      0.01      0.00     99.41
04:05:01 AM     all      0.32      0.00      0.30      0.01      0.00     99.37
04:15:01 AM     all      0.37      0.00      0.31      0.01      0.00     99.32
04:25:01 AM     all      1.78      2.04      0.59      0.05      0.00     95.55
```

To filter out those where `%iowait` is greater than, let's say, `0.01`:

```
sar -u | awk '$7>0.01{print}'
Linux 4.4.0-127-generic (v1)    06/12/2018      _x86_64_        (1 CPU)
04:25:01 AM     all      1.78      2.04      0.59      0.05      0.00     95.55
05:15:01 AM     all      0.34      0.00      0.32      0.02      0.00     99.32
06:35:01 AM     all      0.33      0.22      1.23      4.48      0.00     93.74
06:45:01 AM     all      0.16      0.00      0.12      0.02      0.00     99.71
10:35:01 AM     all      0.22      0.00      0.13      0.02      0.00     99.63
12:15:01 PM     all      0.42      0.00      0.16      0.03      0.00     99.40
01:45:01 PM     all      0.17      0.00      0.11      0.02      0.00     99.71
04:05:01 PM     all      0.15      0.00      0.12      0.03      0.00     99.70
04:15:01 PM     all      0.42      0.00      0.23      0.10      0.00     99.25
```

**Edit:**

As correctly pointed out by [@Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton), the `awk` code can be shortened to simply `awk '$7>0.01'`, since the default action is to print the current line.

Comment: The `{print}` is redundant - that's the default behavior.

Comment: @EdMorton ofc, I just find `awk` easier to read when in the form *condition* {*action*}.